# How can I figure out the angle I need to turn to back in my RV?

Tags: education, applications

To start out I don't understand advanced math all that well but I have a problem that I think I need it to solve.  Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Given this diagram:

[image]

TS = Trailer Slot
TT = Travel Trailer
TV = Tow Vehicle (In my case, a full size truck)

Is it possible to create a formula to solve for the angle and length in the diagram below?

My theory is if I can get these two values then i can place a marker on the ground where I need to start turning so that I back the trailer into to the slot on the first or second try instead of the 20th.  If someone could tell me the type of math this would be that would even be great, I could at least know what to search for on Google.

Comment: Could this be of interest for you : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264891312_Driver_Assist_for_Backing-Up_a_Vehicle_with_a_Long-Wheelbase_Dual-Axle_Trailer ?

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks, that is a good start